# C# .NET6 Autenticación con JWT

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, autenticación

Soy algo nuevo manejando C# y quería hacer una autenticacion con `JWT` y me puse a inventar pero ahora me tope con un error y creo que tiene que ver con la comunicación entre los 2 servicios.

**Error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'ToolNotes.Persistence.NoteContext' while attempting to activate 'IdentityAPI.Controllers.TokenController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)

1. ***Servicio 1 (ToolsNotes)*** = Posee controladores para traer una lista de notas y una lista de usuario.
2. ***Servicio 2 (IdentityAPI)*** = Se encargaría de la autenticacion por token.

**TokenController** (Controller en el servicio **IdentityAPI**)

```
 [Route("api/token")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TokenController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly NoteContext _noteContext;

        public TokenController(IConfiguration config, NoteContext noteContext)
        {
            _configuration = config;
            _noteContext = noteContext;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(User _userData)//"User" Model desde ToolsNotes la tabla en la BD que contiene info de usuario email, pass...
        {
            if (_userData != null && _userData.Email != null && _userData.Password != null)
            {
                var user = await GetUser(_userData.Email, _userData.Password);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    var claims = new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["Jwt:Subject"]),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                        new Claim("User", user.UserId.ToString()),
                        new Claim("DisplayName", user.DisplayName),
                        new Claim("Name", user.UserName),
                        new Claim("Email", user.Email)
                    };

                    var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
                    var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
                    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                        _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                        claims,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                        signingCredentials: signIn);

                    return Ok(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
               }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Invalid Credentials");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        private async Task<User> GetUser(string email, string password)
        {
            return await _noteContext.Usuarios.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == email && u.Password == password);
        }
    }
```

**Métodos del servicio** (ToolsNotes)

```
public interface INote_Service
    {
        IEnumerable<Note> GetNotesService();//Get
        Task<ActionResult<Note>> GetNoteServiceId(Guid id);//Get by ID
        Task<ActionResult<Note>> PostNoteService(Note newNote);//Post
    }

public interface IUser_Service
   {
        IEnumerable<User> GetUsers();
   }
```

**Program.cs de IdentityAPI**

```
 //configs y usings...
    
    builder.Services.AddSqlServer<NoteContext>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));//Solucion al primer error (Error anterior)
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
        };
    });
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    
    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    //...swagger
    
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    //...
```

**Programc.cs de ToolsNotes**

```
// configs y usings...

builder.Services.AddSqlServer<NoteContext>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));

builder.Services.AddScoped<INote_Service, NoteService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUser_Service, UserService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
/swagger...

app.UseAuthorization();
//...
```

***appsettings.json*** de IdentityAPI

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApiSettings": {
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:5004/"
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "Yh2k7QSu4l8CZg5p6X3Pna9L0Miy4D3Bvt0JVr87UcOj69Kqw5R2Nmf4FWs03Hdx",
    "Issuer": "JWTAuthenticationServer",
    "Audience": "JWTServicePostmanClient",
    "Subject": "JWTServiceAccessToken"
  }
}
```

Lo estoy haciendo ayudandome de una doc que encontré pero alli lo hacen todo en un solo proyecto, yo quisiera hacer lo mismo pero que toda la lógica de la autenticacion este en otro proyecto, supongo que hay alguna manera de hacerlo, no se si lo este haciendo mal igual  cualquier respuesta es bienvenida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en que tu proyecto IdentityApi también necesita acceso a la base de datos si vas a usar el NoteContext.

Creo que te falta la línea:

```
builder.Services.AddSqlServer<NoteContext>(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"));
```

En el Program.cs del IdentityApi. Comprueba porfa.

Comment: Me funciono mas sin embargo me da ahora otro error pero en el `endpoint` del otro servicio en donde no esta la autenticacion **jwt**. `No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).`

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux eso ya es otra pregunta. Si la respuesta que `bsebe` te ha sido de utilidad, márcala como aceptada, de este modo ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Comment: @fredyfx Listo ya la marque, gracias por la observación.

Comment: Un placer colaborar :D

Comment: Debería entonces deshacer lo que edite?, o sea lo que hace referencia al nuevo error que vendría siendo otra pregunta.

Comment: Sí, deja el escenario claro y directo para que la respuesta clara y directa tenga sentido lógico y al mismo tiempo, evite confusiones.